# Is there a way to pause a stuck script in the chrome debugger?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

Occasionally, while programming JavaScript, I will make a bone headed mistake and can get the page stuck in an infinite loop while it is loading.  I typically will use Chrome for this and, when I get in this state, I cannot do anything with the javascript developer tools.  What I would really like is a break command similar to what can be done within Visual Studio's debugger that will pause the interpreter and display the current line being executed along with the call stack.  Is there any such functionality available.

As an alternative to this, I would be handy to set break points in the code.  Regardless, I need  some way to interrupt the process so that I can determine the cause of the lock-up.

Comment: I don't have Chrome installed to test, but can you "Break on next" like for Firebug?

Comment: My particular error appears to happen while the page loads.  There is no code available in the console.

Comment: You can set break points in Chrome, but you will not want to let the script auto run on load. Set the break point then call the function with an onclick or from the Chrome console.

Comment: There is a pause button in the script tab

Comment: @Amjad: The pause button has no effect while the scripts are shown.

Comment: @Jon It's supposed to pause execution, I use latest dev channel chrome and its working, maybe its broken on the stable version, but essentially the purpose of the pause button is to break on next statement to be executed after being clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a `debugger;` statement somewhere in your code where you want to break execution  and continue stepping from there on with the Step Next, Step Over, etc

Comment: This still does not seem to pause the debugger if the script gets stuck on the document load.  It is very convenient, however.

Comment: This doesn't solve the "bone headed" part of the problem. If we could foresee the infinite loop we wouldn't cause it in the first place. I'd prefer some kind of chrome UI button that would cause the JS interpreter for the page to simply give up immediately.